# Create Mongodb Query Command from Excel sheet Content [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, string, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to create a query from excel sheet content and convert them to command for Mongodb using pymongo.

Here is the simplified format that I read `Parameter` column from excel sheet and add `"'" + s +"':1,"` to each content. Then append all values by  `query=query+i`  to have query string.All is fine when I print query as string but using it in mongo connection No result!

As I find, in debug mode by appending query string some extra characters appear in string like `'{\'p1\':1,\'p2\':1,\'p3\':1,\'p4\':1}'` which seems not correct and some extra characters added to it. there should be another method to append query string to get ride of these!

query string in **debug mode** `'{\'p1\':1,\'p2\':1,\'p3\':1,\'p4\':1}'`

**desire query string** to use in mongo connection `{'p1':1,'p2':1,'p3':1,'p4':1}`

!!! to check my code I added debug result as a comment in front of each line

```
s = df['Parameter']            #(0, "'p1':1,") (1, "'p2':1,") (2, "'p3':1,") (3, "'p4':1,")
s = "'" + s +"':1,"           
for i in s:
      query=query+i            #'\'p1\':1,\'p2\':1,\'p3\':1,\'p4\':1,'
query="{"+query+"}"
query=query.replace(",}","}")
print(query)                  #'{\'p1\':1,\'p2\':1,\'p3\':1,\'p4\':1}'

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["S"]              # Database Name
col = db["H"]                 # Collection Name
x = col.find({}, query)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally your approach will never work because the `filter` parameter to your `find()` must be a `dict` and you're trying to create a `str` that looks like a `dict`.

You didn't show in your code what the spreadsheet looks like, but say it called `c:/temp/query.xlsx` and looks like this:

[image]

Then your code becomes just a few lines:

```
df = pd.read_excel('c:/temp/query.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col='Parameter')
query = df.to_dict().get('Include')
print(query)
```

result:

```
{'p1': 1, 'p2': 1, 'p3': 1, 'p4': 1}
```

Comment: right point, I had to create a dictionary! thanks for your hint